# Get user defined date String from javascript date object

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I have a javascript Date object as below

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d); //2019-11-28T04:27:43.268Z
```

I want this date to be formatted according to the user preference

```
Eg:
  d-m-y : 28-11-2019
  m-y-d : 11-2019-28
  y-d-m : 2019-28-11 
  ...... etc
```

Is there any way to do this in javascript without manually format the date(using regex or something else)?

**Note:** In Java I can achieve this by using `DateFormat` class `format(Date date)` method from the JDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Day.js API for easy conversion functions on date parameters.

> Day.js

formatting DateTime
Day.js objects are formatted with the format() function.

[Day.js github Link](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs)

Comment: Thanks. This what exactly I want. Working perfectly

Comment: An answer shouldn't rely on a library not mentioned or tagged in the OP. There are a large number of [javascript date libraries](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=javascript+date+libraries), the OP should do their own research to determine which suits them best. Day.js uses different tokens to those in the OP. If the only required tokens are y, m and d, a simple formatter is probably less than 20 lines of code.